# Writing an expression as a product of products

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, products

I am currently dealing with the following expression: $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N-1}(\lambda_N-\lambda_i)\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}(\lambda_{N-1}-\lambda_i)\right)\cdots (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)$$ Is there a way to simplify this even further? I am relatively unfamiliar with notation of the sort: $$\sum\sum \text{or} \prod\prod$$ How may I write it in this form?

Comment: There is a way using the double prod. Just note that you have a product of products which is described by descending length. In this way you can index the inner product so that it is decreasing.

Comment: A shorter notation for this (which is quite commonly used) is $\prod_{i>j}^N(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)$. This means the product over all pairs $i,j=1,2,\ldots,N$ satisfying $i>j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that for every integer $2 \leq k \leq N$ the $k$th term takes the form
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(\lambda_{k} - \lambda_{i}),$$ 
so the desired form is obtained by multiplying all the $N-1$ terms together, which is
$$\prod_{k=2}^{N}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(\lambda_{k} - \lambda_{i}).$$